# Error: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php

I have a JavaScript code that returns values of a PHP and assembles an HTML table. Is giving the error can not read property of each undefined. I've looked several times without success. They could give me a hand?
The following code:

JavaScript:

```js
function getListaItems(idprojeto) {
  //alert(idprojeto);
 jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "get-lista-items.php?idprojeto=" + idprojeto,
  //data: dataEvento,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(resposta) {
   var str_html = '';
   $.each(resposta, function(){
    str_html = str_html + '<tr class="gradeA" id="' + this.id + '">' +
        '<td class="center"><input type="checkbox"  id="item[]" name="item[]" onchange="changeColor(' + this.id + ')" value="' + this.id + '" /></td>' +
        '<td class="center">' + this.descricao + '</td>' +
        '<td class="center">' + this.descCategoria + '</td>' +
        '<td class="center">' + this.descCaracteristica + '</td>' +
        '<td class="center">' + this.descMedida + '</td>' +
        '<td class="center"><input type="text" id="qtd' + this.id + '" style="width:80px"/></td>' +
        '</tr>';
   });

   document.getElementById("resultJs").innerHTML = str_html;
  }
 });
}
```

PHP:

```html
<?php

 session_start();
 require_once("ProjectIncludes.php");

 $service = new ProjetoxItensService();
 $consulta = $service->getAll($_GET['idprojeto']);

 $retorno = json_encode($consulta);
 echo $retorno;

?>
```

Thanks, guys.

Comment: replace `$` with `jQuery`

Comment: It worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like jQuery is not available using `$`, try `jQuery` instead.

Change this line:

```
$.each(resposta, function(){
```

to this:

```
jQuery.each(resposta, function(){
```