# jQuery function won't read properties globally

Tags: jquery, function, global

I'm in the process of streamlining a lot of jQuery code, and the first thing I want to do is to set functions globally so they can be used and reused across the scope. One function is for setting equal heights to elements, based on the highest element:

```
function setEqHeight(cont, classname) {

    var maxHeight = 0;
    $(cont).each(function(){
        var prodName = $(classname,this);
        $(prodName).each(function(){ if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = $(this).height(); } });
        $(prodName).height(maxHeight);
    });

}
```

And I run it like so

```
setEqHeight('.containername','.classname');
```

This works, as long as I call both inside `$j( document ).ready(function($) { });`
But I want to set the function globally, outside the document ready, and call the function inside.

When I set the function outside the document ready scope, and call it inside the scope, I get the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of null` error. Like it isn't able to read the 'containername' anymore. I'm puzzled, what am I doing wrong?

Edit: [jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/6pvssxd8/). It does work properly there, which begs the question why it doesn't in the production environment

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle please .. there is nothing wrong with your code it should work properly like you said

Comment: What are you passing in .containername is it the name of the div or table?

Comment: jsFiddle added; it does work there indeed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36342224/4632458). I think it had to do with the exact environment the script runs in; Magento. Magento doesn't sit well with jQuery out of the box, so I changed the dollar-signs in the function to jQuery like so;

```
function setEqHeight(cont, classname) {

    var maxHeight = 0;
    jQuery(cont).each(function(){
        var prodName = jQuery(classname,this);
        jQuery(prodName).each(function(){ if (jQuery(this).height() > maxHeight) { maxHeight = jQuery(this).height(); } });
        jQuery(prodName).height(maxHeight);
    });

}
```

and now it works properly. Thanks everyone for thinking along.